# Derive/Override the DataMemberAttribute

Tags: c#, serialization, data-binding, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'd like to override some of the functionality of the DataMemberAttribute but cannot create a derived class because it is marked as 'sealed'.

What I would like to do is have EmitDefaultValue be defaulted to 'false' instead of 'true' and I'd also like to not "emit" a collection if it is null or empty.

Any ideas?

---

Commenter wanted an example.  There really isn't a way to show an example and I believe my question is fairly clear.  But what the heck, here goes.

Instead of having to do this on every property:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDto
{
  [DataMember( EmitDefaultValue = false )]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember( EmitDefaultValue = false )]
  public string Occupation { get; set; }

  [DataMember( EmitDefaultValue = false )]
  public List<string> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDto
{
  [CustomSerialization]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [CustomSerialization]
  public string Occupation { get; set; }

  [CustomSerialization]
  public List<string> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

And for the last property "Friends", if it is null or empty, to not serialize it in the output.

Comment: It would be awesome if you create an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of problem.

Comment: It's a very simple class (see [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/DataMemberAttribute.cs)). You could just write your own.

Comment: @JohnWu Sure I could do that but nothing will happen during serialization.  The DataMemberAttribute is used by the serialization engine.  I can't just create a similar class and have it magically work.  It needs to be "wired-up".

Comment: What serializer and data format (XML vs JSON) are you using?  Both the data contract serializers and [tag:json.net] support data contract attributes.

Comment: Both XML and JSON.  The client can decide.  I want to override the default behavior of serializers when a property is null or empty.